# differentiability of $f(x,y)=xy\sin\left({1\over x^2+y^2}\right)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, approximation-theory

Let $f(x,y)=xy\sin\left({1\over x^2+y^2}\right)$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $0$ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Determine the points in which $f$ is differentiable

I know that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ iff there exists a linear function $l:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ so that:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)}{f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)-l(x-x_0,y-y_0)\over \|\vec x - \vec x_0\|}=0$$

If I want to see the points in which $f$ is differentiable then I need to pick an arbitry point $(x_0,y_0)$ but then the last expression becomes very complicated; Is there an easy way do it?
I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: It is usually easier to use theorems that guarantee that , e.g., products, ratios of differentiable functions are differentiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivative exists at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ if the partial derivatives exist in an open neighborhood and are continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$.

This is clearly the case everywhere except possibly $(0,0)$ so the behavior at that point must be examined more closely.

Note that

$$f_x(x,y) = y\sin\left({1\over x^2+y^2}\right)- \frac{2x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\cos\left({1\over x^2+y^2}\right),\\ f_y(x,y) = x\sin\left({1\over x^2+y^2}\right)- \frac{2xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\cos\left({1\over x^2+y^2}\right).$$

Along a path with $y=0$

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0), y=0}f_x(x,y)=0$$

Along a path with $y=x$

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0), y=x}f_x(x,y)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x\sin\left({1\over 2x^2}\right)-\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{2x^3}{4x^4}\cos\left({1\over 2x^2}\right)=0 \pm \infty.$$

Hence, the partial derivatives are not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Since continuity of the partial derivatives is a sufficient condition for the existence of the derivative, we cannot conclude non-existence at this point.

Notice that

$$\frac{|f(x,y)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leqslant \frac{|x||y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leqslant \min(|x|,|y|).$$

So try using $l:(x,y)\mapsto 0$.

Then

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-l(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\sin\left({1\over x^2+y^2}\right)=0,$$

and the derivative at $(0,0)$ is the zero linear operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I really appreciate your help @RRL. Very clear answer :D

Comment: @user128422: You're welcome.

Comment: Could you clarify the limit $0 \pm \infty$? I.e. why is that the limit of the expression?

Comment: @mavavilj: The first term $x \sin(1/(2x^2)) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ since the sine factor is bounded. The second term is oscillatory and unbounded since $\cos(1/(2x^2))$ oscillates between $+1$ and $-1$ and the factor $(2x^3)/(4x^4) = 1/(2x)$ diverges to $+\infty$ as $x \to 0+$ and $-\infty$ as $x \to 0-$. Overall we would say limit does not exist.