# Reconciling different definitions of differentiability in multi-dimensions.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

We have from this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions), the definition of differentiability:

$$\lim_{\mathbf{h}\to \mathbf{0}} \frac{\|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x_0}+\mathbf{h}) - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x_0}) - \mathbf{J}\mathbf{(h)}\|}{\| \mathbf{h} \|} = 0.$$

Where $J$ is a linear function. This means,
$$\lim_{\mathbf{h}\to \mathbf{0}} \frac{\|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x_0}+\mathbf{h}) - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x_0}) \|}{\| \mathbf{h} \|} = \lim_{\mathbf{h}\to \mathbf{0}}\frac{\mathbf{J}\mathbf{(h)}}{\|h\|}.$$

Assuming we're coming into the point along the direction $\vec{v}$ (a unit vector), we can say $h=t.\vec{v}$. So we get

$$\lim_{\mathbf{h}\to \mathbf{0}} \frac{\|\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x_0}+\mathbf{h}) - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x_0}) \|}{\| \mathbf{h} \|} = \lim_{\mathbf{t}\to 0}\frac{\mathbf{J}\mathbf{(t\vec{v})}}{t} = \lim_{\mathbf{t}\to 0} \frac{t\mathbf{J}\mathbf{(\vec{v})}}{t} = \mathbf{J}\mathbf{(\vec{v})}.$$
This implies that the limit on the left should be linear in the components of $\vec{v}$. Another way of putting it is that the tangent lines along various directions should lie on a plane. This was the technique @Rene used in the question [I asked yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678774/prove-function-is-not-differentiable-even-though-all-directional-derivatives-exi).

This is all well and good, but then I saw this other definition of differentiability [here](https://mathinsight.org/differentiability_multivariable_theorem). This one says - 
"If, for a function all the partial derivatives of its matrix of partial derivatives exist and are continuous in a neighborhood of the point, it is differentiable". Screenshot -

[image]

Now, I'm finding it hard to reconcile these two definitions. It seems to me the first one is much stricter than the second one. I imagine there might be a function where the derivatives are all continuous, but the tangent lines they correspond to don't lie on a plane. The first condition would seem to imply it's not differentiable while the second one would imply it is. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your second formula above is wrong.

Comment: @copper.hat, are you saying the link I pasted referencing it is incorrect? Or am I misinterpreting it? Someone also mentioned they saw the same definition in a book.

Comment: No. I am saying that your second formula above is wrong. After "This means...". I have no idea where you got that formula from.

Comment: @copper.hat - I really hope you are right :)

Comment: Where did you get that formula from???

Comment: From the link - https://mathinsight.org/differentiability_multivariable_theorem, see the third paragraph, section labeled "Differentiability theorem"

Comment: A counter example to what?

Comment: I see no formula on that page.

Comment: The third paragraph is labeled "Differentiability theorem" in bold. Do you see it now?

Comment: This is a bit of a time waste. I see nothing resembling your second formula above.

Comment: Ok, I clicked and checked the link multiple times and I see it. So, I pasted a screenshot of what I see and edited it into the question. This way, you can hopefully see what I see.

Comment: This is the end of the line for me. I will say it one more time, the formula you have after "This means..." is incorrect, in fact meaningless. I have no idea where you got that from. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, I see what you meant now. The second formula just involves taking one part of the equation to the other side. In any case, the conclusion from it (derivative has to be linear around point) has been used before. For example, in the answer by Rene to the question - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678774/prove-function-is-not-differentiable-even-though-all-directional-derivatives-exi

Answer (score 3):

Your first limit is the definition. If such a linear function $J$ exists then the function $f$ is differentiable and it can be shown that $J$ is unique.  The existence of the derivative guarantees the existence of all directional (and partial) derivatives

$$D_vf(x) = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(x + t \, v) - f(x)}{t},$$

but the existence of directional derivatives at $x$ is not enough to conclude that $f$ is differentiable by the first definition.

What you are calling the second definition is a theorem that guarantees that the derivative $J$ exists at $x$ -- under fairly strong conditions that the partial derivatives exist in a neighborhood and are continuous at $x$.

An example where the derivative exists at the point $(0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ but the partial derivatives are not continuous at the point is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1047814/148510).

To prove the theorem for a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ where $f(x) = (f_1(x), \ldots, f_n(x))$ it is enough to prove that each component $f_k:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ has a derivative.  An example of the proof is given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1026274/148510).

Comment: But isn't it possible as per the second definition that all partial derivatives exist in the neighborhood of $x$ and are continuous at x too, but their corresponding tangent lines don't lie on a plane? This kind of function would seem to violate the first condition but satisfy the second, no?

Comment: Your intuition is not correct.  But it is true that the partial derivatives are not coplanar in the sense you describe.  In fact they are directional derivatives in the directions given by the orthogonal basis vectors. It would probably help if you looked at how this theorem (not definition) is proved.  I'll look for a good link.

Comment: just to be clear, your position is that the two definitions of differentiability are equivalent, correct?

Comment: No, the first is the definition.  The second statement is a theorem that provides a sufficient condition for the derivative to exist. It's possible the derivative exists even if the conditions of the theorem don't hold.

Comment: But then why do they say - "then f(x) is differentiable" instead of saying "then the derivative exists"? This is the part that's been confusing me.

Comment: To say $f$ is differentiable at $x$ is the same as saying the derivative $J$ exists at $x$.  I just added a link in the answer of an example where the theorem does not hold, but the derivative exists.

Comment: I also added a link to one of my answers where I prove the theorem.  Hope that helps.